# Cor.test to a subset of variables in data frame

Tags: r, apply, correlation

I'm new to R and I'm looking for a way to apply cor.test selectively to a set of variables in a data frame. I have made a small script myself to view and then select out a set of correlations from cor(dataframe) results. What I would like to do next is to run cor.test on all these results that have coefficients with absolute value larger than X.

My script

```
    sortedcorlist <- function(mydataframe,method,numtoreport)
  {
   vahe<-cor(mydataframe, method=method)
   diag(vahe) <- 0
  vahe2 <- as.data.frame(vahe)
  vahe2 <- vahe2[c("axis1", "axis2", "axis3")]
  vahe2 <- as.matrix(vahe2)
  vahe2 <- as.table(vahe2)
  vahe2 <- as.data.frame(vahe2)
  head(vahe2[order(abs(vahe2[3]),decreasing=T),],n=numtoreport)
  }
If I run it on a dataframe like.

axis1   axis2   axis3   Alphaproteobacteria Actinobacteria  Gammaproteobacteria Solibacteres    Deltaproteobacteria
-0.118764   -0.028032   0.16921 15.5712530713   5.5282555283    5.773955774 11.9164619165   7.2788697789
-0.277526   0.081097    -0.079291   15.6943303205   12.2432210353   8.5456039441    5.7518488085    5.9983566146
-0.049546   0.002888    0.108965    17.9294117647   7.937254902 6.0235294118    13.0039215686   4.9098039216
-0.225758   0.043167    -0.022499   13.6838868389   12.5768757688   6.2423124231    7.3800738007    6.2115621156
0.004122    -0.017673   -0.020766   16.6099387338   11.708645337    6.3308373043    6.6712049013    5.1055139551
0.194926    -0.140736   -0.105162   17.6307007786   9.1768631813    8.1757508343    6.1179087875    3.5595105673
0.036636    0.001613    0.097292    17.1144859813   10.8644859813   6.4836448598    8.8785046729    6.4252336449
0.227766    0.321532    0.0225  17.8297278437   11.5143056525   6.5945568737    12.805303559    3.5589672017
-0.013657   -0.049475   0.145208    15.5555555556   5.7023060797    6.1635220126    12.2431865828   6.750524109
0.143307    -0.040705   0.104411    20.9752839011   7.4816299265    3.7408149633    12.4248496994   5.3440213761
```

I can get a listed output for the correlations I'm interested in.

```
sortedcorlist(klassmuld,"kendall",30)
                  Var1  Var2       Freq
9   Betaproteobacteria axis1 -0.7333333
10       Acidobacteria axis1  0.7333333
37      Actinobacteria axis3 -0.6888889
12      Spartobacteria axis1 -0.6000000
38 Gammaproteobacteria axis3 -0.5555556
4  Alphaproteobacteria axis1  0.5111111
39        Solibacteres axis3  0.5111111
29       Phycisphaerae axis2 -0.4666667
8  Deltaproteobacteria axis1 -0.4222222
21      Actinobacteria axis2  0.4222222
11     Sphingobacteria axis1 -0.3777778
26       Acidobacteria axis2 -0.3777778
40 Deltaproteobacteria axis3  0.3777778
45       Phycisphaerae axis3  0.3777778
2                axis2 axis1 -0.2888889
15               SJA.4 axis1 -0.2888889
17               axis1 axis2 -0.2888889
22 Gammaproteobacteria axis2  0.2888889
25  Betaproteobacteria axis2  0.2888889
7         Solibacteres axis1  0.2444444
47               SJA.4 axis3  0.2444444
19               axis3 axis2 -0.2000000
24 Deltaproteobacteria axis2 -0.2000000
32             Bacilli axis2 -0.2000000
34               axis2 axis3 -0.2000000
6  Gammaproteobacteria axis1  0.1555556
14    Verrucomicrobiae axis1  0.1555556
28      Spartobacteria axis2  0.1555556
43     Sphingobacteria axis3  0.1555556
46    Verrucomicrobiae axis3  0.1555556
```

So I can see which correlations (for axis1,2,3 I'm interested in) have absolute values larger than let's say 0.5. Now I would like to feed these pairs of column names (for 0.5 then from Betaproteobacteria/axis1 to Solibacteres/axis3) to cor.test on the first dataframe.

I'm really new to R programming and the amount of different "apply" functions etc. is just confusing already. I guess one of this should be the one to use+ Or should I go with some kind of for loop?

Comment: I think it's easier to work with `corr.test` from package `psych`. You can pass your dataframe as an argument and get all pairwise correlations.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'll use psych for the most immediate tasks. Then someday I still have to figure this thing here out. It seems to have most of the functionality I need - (tends to abbreviate the column names horribly though, but I can just use some easily identifiable codenames there, bigger problem is it seems to only produce p-values with two decimal points)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the value of `sortedcorlist(klassmuld,"kendall",30)` to a name, say "sorted.cors" you can then store the results and then select which rows meet your specs and run your cor.test on the pairwise columns:

```
sorted.cors <- sortedcorlist(klassmuld,"kendall",30)
targets <- sorted.cors[sorted.cors[['Freq']] > 0.5 , ]
apply(targets, 1, function(ro) cor.test( klassmuld[[ ro[1] ]],
                                         klassmuld[[ ro[2] ]])$statistic )
# With your example data I get:
       4       23 
2.897042 4.180236
```

Notice that it is the rownames that become the names of the resultant vector.

Comment: Very nice - I was thinking on something like this myself - but as said I'm rahter new to R (and its style of programming seems so different to anything else I've dabbled with)

Comment: So I understand that ro[1] and 2 are first and second elements from a current row in "targets" and wrapping them into [ro[]] will mean their values(names) will be used to take appropriate slices/columns from klassmuld. Lots of thing seem clearer today - thank you again for your answer.